# Problemas com Angular Material

Tags: angular

Estou tentando inserir um componente "dialog" do Angular Material, porém o console esta exibindo do seguinte erro que não consigo solucionar:

> WARNING in ./src/app/app.module.ts 19:16-31 "export 'DialogComponent'
>   was not found in './dialog/dialog.component' i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with
>   warnings.
>
> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/munir.junior/Desktop/iob-educacao/src/app/dialog/dialog.component"'
>   has no exported member 'DialogComponent'.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialog/dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    DialogComponent,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: como ta o codigo do seu app.module?

Comment: de que forma posso te enviar o código?

Comment: edita a pergunta com o codigo

Comment: coloquei o código ao app.module na pergunta, mas não fica formatado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importe o modulo inves de redeclarar o componente do material.

```
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BannerComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

O seu erro está ocorrendo por que o **MatDialogModule** está em **declarations** e não no imports, também não é preciso importar o **DialogComponent** no seu module e sim apenas no seu componente (.ts). Tente troca-los de lugar e provavelmente irá funcionar, Espero ter ajudado.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialog/dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    **DialogComponent**,
    **MatDialogModule**
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

Todo componente que será usado como dialog deve ser colocado em **declarations** e em **entryComponents** dentro do seu `app.module.ts`, como a seguir:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialog/dialog.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        BannerComponent,
        DialogComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatDialogModule 
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [
        DialogComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Recomendo você criar um novo módulo para colocar seus módulos do Angular Material, da seguinte forma:

1. Crie um novo arquivo `.ts` no seu projeto (pode ser na mesma pasta de `app.module.ts`) e dê um nome qualquer, como `material.module.ts`.
2. Dentro deste arquivo, defina o layout básico:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    exports: []
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

3. Importe os módulos dos componentes do Angular Material que deseja trabalhar, como o `MatDialogModule`.

```
// Para habilitar o uso de 'dialog'
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

4. Crie uma variável para guardar a referência aos módulos logo abaixo das importações:

```
const materialModules = [MatDialogModule];
```

5. Adicione a variável criada acima ao `imports` e `exports` no `@NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...materialModules],
    exports: [...materialModules]
})
```

Seu `material.module.ts` ficará assim:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Para habilitar o uso de 'dialog'
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

const materialModules = [MatDialogModule];

@NgModule({
    imports: [...materialModules],
    exports: [...materialModules]
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

6. Agora, importe dentro do seu `app.module.ts` o arquivo que você acabou de editar e coloque sua referência dentro de `imports` do `@NgModule`:

```
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
```

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MaterialModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        BannerComponent,
        DialogComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [
        DialogComponent
    ]
})
```

Assim, seu código fica mais limpo e bem mais tranquilo de trabalhar. Sempre que você quiser usar um novo componente do Angular Material é só adicionar o módulo em `material.module.ts` da mesma forma que o `MatDialogModule`. Por exemplo, se você quiser adicionar o módulo de tabelas:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Para habilitar o uso de 'dialog'
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
// Para habilitar o uso de 'table'
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

const materialModules = [MatDialogModule, MatTableModule];

@NgModule({
    imports: [...materialModules],
    exports: [...materialModules]
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

Abraços!